# How would I sort an Array of Std Class Objects by specific listing order?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, stdclass

I have an array of StdClass Objects and that contains several different Car Types (ex. Compact Car, Minivan, etc.) which is sorted by price. I would like to sort the array in the following order:

- Economy Car
- Compact Car
- Mid-Size Car
- Standard-Size Car
- Full-Size Car
- Premium Car
- Luxury Car
- Standard-Size Convertible
- Mid-Size SUV
- Standard SUV
- Full-Size SUV
- Minivan
- **Remaining cars sorted by price**

I'm not sure if it makes sense to sort this order using key "description" or "codes". I've figured out how to sort by price, but not sure how to reorder the array in the above order listed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Input Array:

```
    array (
    0 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Mid-Size SUV',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'IFAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '5',
       'min_people' => '5',
       'max_bags' => '4',
       'min_bags' => '1',
       'price' => '30.31',
    )),
    1 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Standard-Size SUV',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'SFAR',
        1 => 'RFAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '7',
       'min_people' => '5',
       'max_bags' => '4',
       'min_bags' => '1',
       'price' => '35.53',
    )),
    2 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Specialty Vehicle',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'XXAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => false,
       'min_people' => false,
       'max_bags' => '',
       'min_bags' => '',
       'price' => '36.72',
    )),
    3 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Compact Car',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'CCAR',
        1 => 'CDAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '5',
       'min_people' => '4',
       'max_bags' => '3',
       'min_bags' => '1',
       'price' => '37.21',
    )),
    4 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Economy Car',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'ECAR',
        1 => 'EDAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '5',
       'min_people' => '4',
       'max_bags' => '2',
       'min_bags' => '1',
       'price' => '37.21',
    )),
    5 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Mid-Size Car',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'ICAR',
        1 => 'IDAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '5',
       'min_people' => '5',
       'max_bags' => '4',
       'min_bags' => '1',
       'price' => '39.46',
    )),
    6 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Standard-Size Car',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'SCAR',
        1 => 'SDAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '5',
       'min_people' => '5',
       'max_bags' => '4',
       'min_bags' => '1',
       'price' => '41.77',
    )),
    7 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Minivan',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'MVAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '7',
       'min_people' => '7',
       'max_bags' => '5',
       'min_bags' => '2',
       'price' => '43.18',
    )),
    8 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Full-Size Car',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'FCAR',
        1 => 'FDAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '5',
       'min_people' => '5',
       'max_bags' => '4',
       'min_bags' => '1',
       'price' => '43.50',
    )),
    9 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Compact SUV',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'CFAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '5',
       'min_people' => '5',
       'max_bags' => '3',
       'min_bags' => '3',
       'price' => '46.42',
    )),
    10 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Full-Size Hybrid',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'FCAH',
      ),
       'max_people' => false,
       'min_people' => false,
       'max_bags' => '',
       'min_bags' => '',
       'price' => '48.00',
    )),
    11 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Standard-Size Convertible',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'STAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '4',
       'min_people' => '4',
       'max_bags' => '4',
       'min_bags' => '1',
       'price' => '48.39',
    )),
    12 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Sports Car',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'XSAR',
        1 => 'SSAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '5',
       'min_people' => '4',
       'max_bags' => '3',
       'min_bags' => '1',
       'price' => '48.72',
    )),
    13 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Premium Car',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'PCAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '5',
       'min_people' => '5',
       'max_bags' => '4',
       'min_bags' => '2',
       'price' => '48.72',
    )),
    14 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Luxury Car',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'LCAR',
        1 => 'LDAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '5',
       'min_people' => '5',
       'max_bags' => '5',
       'min_bags' => '1',
       'price' => '52.16',
    )),
    15 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Full-Size SUV',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'FFAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '8',
       'min_people' => '7',
       'max_bags' => '4',
       'min_bags' => '2',
       'price' => '52.92',
    )),
    16 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Full-Size Van',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'FVAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '15',
       'min_people' => '12',
       'max_bags' => '5',
       'min_bags' => '1',
       'price' => '90.38',
    )),
    17 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Compact Convertible',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'CTAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '4',
       'min_people' => '4',
       'max_bags' => '1',
       'min_bags' => '1',
       'price' => '91.17',
    )),
    18 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Premium SUV',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'PFAR',
        1 => 'UFAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '7',
       'min_people' => '5',
       'max_bags' => '5',
       'min_bags' => '1',
       'price' => '92.64',
    )),
    19 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Specialty Car',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'XCAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '5',
       'min_people' => '5',
       'max_bags' => '3',
       'min_bags' => '3',
       'price' => '94.42',
    )),
    20 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Mid-Size Convertible',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'ITAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '4',
       'min_people' => '4',
       'max_bags' => '2',
       'min_bags' => '2',
       'price' => '97.98',
    )),
    21 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Luxury SUV',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'LFAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '5',
       'min_people' => '5',
       'max_bags' => '3',
       'min_bags' => '3',
       'price' => '113.66',
    )),
    22 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Premium Convertible',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'PTAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '4',
       'min_people' => '4',
       'max_bags' => '1',
       'min_bags' => '1',
       'price' => '121.15',
    )),
    23 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Luxury Convertible',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'LTAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '4',
       'min_people' => '4',
       'max_bags' => '1',
       'min_bags' => '1',
       'price' => '129.01',
    )),
    24 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Premium Van',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'PVAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '15',
       'min_people' => '15',
       'max_bags' => '1',
       'min_bags' => '1',
       'price' => '159.49',
    )),
    25 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'description' => 'Specialty Convertible',
       'codes' => 
      array (
        0 => 'XTAR',
      ),
       'max_people' => '4',
       'min_people' => '4',
       'max_bags' => '2',
       'min_bags' => '2',
       'price' => '307.64',
    )),
  )
```

**Code:**

```
usort($car_types,function($a,$b) {
    return $a->price == $b->price ? 0 : $a->price > $b->price;
});

usort($car_types, function($a, $b) use ($order) {
    $a_set = intval(isset($order[$a->description]));
    $b_set = intval(isset($order[$b->description]));

    return $a_set === $b_set && $a_set === 1
    ? $order[$a->description] - $order[$b->description]
    : $b_set - $a_set;
});
```

Comment: Add a `sort order` value to the object and sort using that.

Comment: you need to give some sort order to these types and then you can sort. Or you have to create a predefined array with these names and then based on those names sort your array.

Answer (score 0):

Define ordering array and use it inside [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
$order = [
    'Economy Car' => 1,
    'Compact Car' => 2,
    'Mid-Size Car' => 3,
    'Standard-Size Car' => 4,
    'Full-Size Car' => 5,
    'Premium Car' => 6,
    'Luxury Car' => 7,
    'Standard-Size Convertible' => 8,
    'Mid-Size SUV' => 9,
    'Standard SUV' => 10,
    'Full-Size SUV' => 11,
    'Minivan' => 12
];

usort($car_types, function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
    static $notSetPriority;

    $aPriority = isset($order[$a->description])
        ? $order[$a->description]
        : $notSetPriority ?? ($notSetPriority = count($order) + 1);
    $bPriority = isset($order[$b->description])
        ? $order[$b->description]
        : $notSetPriority;

    if (($comparison = $aPriority - $bPriority ) === 0) {
        return floatval($a->price) - floatval($b->price);
    }

    return $comparison;
});
```

If the order weight for the description is not set, then we give it a weight of most weight plus one.

Do not apply [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) more than once, because it is hard to predict the result that way. I have combined both sorting criteria into one.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect. One thing: For the remaining cars that aren't defined in $order (such as Mid-Size Specialty Vehicle)...how can I sort the remaining cars by price? So for example after Minivan should come Mid-Size Specialty Vehicle, Compact SUV, Standard-Size Pickup, Specialty Vehicle and so on...

Comment: @MichaelAlterio, sort an array by price first (apply `usort` that you specified in the question), then sort by description (`usort` from the answer). This should do the trick.

Comment: I've updated the original post with a sorted by price (lowest to highest) Input Array. When I usort by price and then use the order usort above, it's not sorting by lowest to highest price after the order. Any ideas what's happening?

Comment: @MichaelAlterio, if you provide your input array with `var_export` (instead of `var_dump` or `print_r`), so I can copy paste it and try, I will try to find out what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the Input Array with var_export. Let me know what you find.